# Mismatch data within intents

Tags: java, android

I have an issue with mismatch data between putting data to intent and reading it.
In my service I'm creating notification and adding parameters to the intent.
When i see the notification the paramters is ok. But when I open the notification the parameters act wired. I get true parameters in my system but no the once i sent.
is this problem because I'm creating notification in my service?

```
public void createNotification(ChatMessage message) 
{

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_action_sm, 
                                                 "Message From" +
                                                 " " + message.getSenderName(),
                                                 System.currentTimeMillis());

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("userProfile", message.getReciverChatProfile());        
    intent.putExtra("friendProfile", message.getSenderChatProfile());

    PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this,
                                    message.getSenderName(),
                                    message.getMessage(),
                                    activity);
    notification.number += 1;
    notification.iconLevel = 3;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT solved the problem.

```
PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```